# How do i change the background color of this snake game?

Tags: java, text, colors, background, applet

Hello i just recently was watching a tutorial on how to create a snake game in java. 
Here it is if you want to go check it out http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=07UdiMlvDcI this is part 4 he has more parts to it.

I copied his tutorial but i would like to add a few things of my own to it. I was just wondering if any of you know how to change the background to black. I am a big noob to java and need lots of help. There also other things that i would like to know how to do like for example is. How do i change the Highscore or Score text to BOLD or place it in a different location. Also wouldnt mind knowing how to change the color of the head or replace the head with a image that i downloaded. Also another thing is how do i change the size of the window, when i change the dimension it doesnt change anything. The second class at the bottom might be more useful for you guys because thats where the tutorial guy made his applet. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

CODE:

```
public class SnakeCanvas extends Canvas implements Runnable, KeyListener{
    private final int BOX_HEIGHT = 10;
    private final int BOX_WIDTH = 10;
    private final int GRID_WIDTH = 25;
    private final int GRID_HEIGHT = 25;

    private LinkedList<Point> snake;
    private Point fruit;
    private int direction = Direction.NO_DIRECTION;

    private Thread runThread;
    private int score = 0;
    private String highscore = "";

    public void init() {

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        if (snake == null) {
            snake = new LinkedList<Point>();
            GenerateDefaultSnake();
            PlaceFruit();
        }

    if (runThread == null) {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640, 480));
        this.addKeyListener(this);
        runThread = new Thread(this);
        runThread.start();
    }

    if (highscore.equals("")) {
        highscore = this.GetHighScore();
    }

    drawFruit(g);
    drawGrid(g);
    drawSnake(g);
    drawScore(g);

}

public void update(Graphics g) {
    Graphics offScreenGraphics; //Graphics used to draw offscreen
    BufferedImage offscreen = null;
    Dimension d = this.getSize();

    offscreen = new BufferedImage(d.width, d.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    offScreenGraphics = offscreen.getGraphics();
    offScreenGraphics.setColor(this.getBackground());//CHANGE BACKGROUND COLOR
    offScreenGraphics.fillRect(0, 0, d.width, d.height);
    offScreenGraphics.setColor(this.getForeground());
    paint(offScreenGraphics);

    //flip
    g.drawImage(offscreen, 0, 0, this);
}

public void GenerateDefaultSnake() {
    score = 0;
    snake.clear();

    snake.add(new Point(0,2));
    snake.add(new Point(0,1));
    snake.add(new Point(0,0));
    direction = Direction.NO_DIRECTION;

}


public void Move() {
    Point head = snake.peekFirst();
    Point newPoint = head;
    switch(direction) {
        case Direction.NORTH:
            newPoint = new Point(head.x, head.y - 1);
            break;
        case Direction.SOUTH:
            newPoint = new Point (head.x, head.y + 1);
            break;
        case Direction.WEST:
            newPoint = new Point (head.x - 1, head.y);
            break;
        case Direction.EAST:
            newPoint = new Point (head.x + 1, head.y);
            break;
    }

snake.remove(snake.peekLast());

if(newPoint.equals(fruit)){
  score+=10;
  //the snake has hit fruit
  Point addPoint = (Point) newPoint.clone();

  switch(direction){
  case Direction.NORTH:
    newPoint = new Point(head.x, head.y-1);
    break;
  case Direction.SOUTH:
    newPoint = new Point (head.x, head.y+1);
    break;
  case Direction.WEST:
    newPoint = new Point (head.x-1, head.y);
    break;
  case Direction.EAST:
    newPoint = new Point (head.x+1, head.y);
    break;
}
  snake.push(addPoint);
  PlaceFruit();
}
else if(newPoint.x < 0 || newPoint.x > GRID_WIDTH - 1){
  //we went out of bounce, reset game
 CheckScore();
 GenerateDefaultSnake();
 return;
}
else if(newPoint.y < 0 || newPoint.y > GRID_HEIGHT - 1){
  //we went out of bounce, reset game
  CheckScore();
  GenerateDefaultSnake();
  return;
}
else if(snake.contains(newPoint)){
  //we ran into ourselves, reset game
  CheckScore();
  GenerateDefaultSnake();
  return;
}

//if we reach this point in code, we're still alive
snake.push(newPoint);
}

 public void drawScore(Graphics g){
 g.drawString("Score: " + score, 0, BOX_HEIGHT * GRID_HEIGHT + 10);
 g.drawString("HighScore: " + highscore, 0, BOX_HEIGHT * GRID_HEIGHT + 20);
 }

 public void CheckScore(){
 if(highscore.equals(""))
  return;

  if(score > Integer.parseInt((highscore.split(":")[1]))){
  String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("NEW HIGHSCORE! PLEASE ENTER YOUR NAME.");
  highscore = name + ":" + score;

  File scoreFile = new File("highscore.dat");
  if(!scoreFile.exists()){
    try{
    scoreFile.createNewFile();
  }
  catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  }
  FileWriter writeFile = null;
  BufferedWriter writer = null;
  try{
    writeFile = new FileWriter(scoreFile);
    writer = new BufferedWriter(writeFile);
    writer.write(this.highscore);
  }
  catch(Exception e){
  }
  finally{
    try{
    if(writer !=null)
      writer.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){}
   }
   }
   }



   public void drawGrid(Graphics g){
   //drawing an outside rectangle
   g.drawRect(0, 0, GRID_WIDTH * BOX_WIDTH, GRID_HEIGHT * BOX_HEIGHT);

   }

public void drawSnake(Graphics g){
g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
for (Point p: snake){
  g.fillRect(p.x * BOX_WIDTH, p.y * BOX_HEIGHT, BOX_WIDTH, BOX_HEIGHT);
}
g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
}

public void drawFruit(Graphics g){
g.setColor(Color.RED);
g.fillOval(fruit.x * BOX_WIDTH, fruit.y * BOX_HEIGHT, BOX_WIDTH, BOX_HEIGHT);
g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
  }


public void PlaceFruit(){
Random rand = new Random();
int randomX = rand.nextInt(GRID_WIDTH);
int randomY = rand.nextInt(GRID_HEIGHT);
Point randomPoint = new Point(randomX, randomY);
while(snake.contains(randomPoint)){
  randomX = rand.nextInt(GRID_WIDTH);
  randomY = rand.nextInt(GRID_HEIGHT);
  randomPoint = new Point (randomX, randomY);
}
 fruit = randomPoint; 
}

@Override
public void run(){
while(true){//runs indefinitely
  Move();
  repaint();

  try{
    Thread.currentThread();
    Thread.sleep(100);
  }
  catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}

}

public String GetHighScore(){

FileReader readFile = null;
BufferedReader reader = null; 

try{
readFile = new FileReader("highscore.dat");
reader = new BufferedReader(readFile);
return reader.readLine();
}
catch(Exception e){
  return "Nobody:0";
}

finally{
  try{
    if(reader != null)
    reader.close();
  }
  catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}

}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){
//TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
switch (e.getKeyCode())
{
case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
if (direction != Direction.SOUTH)
direction = Direction.NORTH;
break;
case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
if (direction != Direction.NORTH)
direction = Direction.SOUTH;
break;
case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
 if (direction != Direction.WEST)
direction = Direction.EAST;
break;
case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
if (direction != Direction.EAST)
direction = Direction.WEST;
break;

}
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){

}



}
```

OTHER CLASS:

```
public class snakeApplet extends Applet{

private SnakeCanvas c;

public void init(){
c = new SnakeCanvas();
c.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640, 480));
c.setVisible(true);
c.setFocusable(true);
this.add(c);
this.setVisible(true);
this.setSize(new Dimension(640, 480));

 }

public void paint(Graphics g){
this.setSize(new Dimension(640, 480));
}
}
```

IM really hoping someone could help me!!!

Comment: The example is a poor example, violates a number if painting rules and would be considered out of date by today's available Apis. Font modify the state of the component within the paint methods or add listeners

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this.setBackground(Color.BLACK); to the paint method in the SnakeCanvas class. If that doesn't work, add the same line to the snakeApplet class. If that doesn't work, I'm sorry I failed you.

Comment: The problem is, you should never change the state of a component in any paint method and in AWT, the update method is responsible for painting the background of the component, but neither is super.update or super.paint called, so there's no chance for component to apply these states

Comment: MR Wole0 i FREAKING LOVE YOU MAN!